# How to get multiple devices trough xhttp.open?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, variables, get

I have s website on my arduino,
I can get 1 x the value but if i do copy the same code and alter it to the id i need to retrieve the second device it doesnt work, only 1 device at the time works... so if i delete 1 of the 2 codes it works...
ANd the thing is i need to add 15 more devices trough that way, and only 1 works at the time.. what can i do now ?

I did try to use a "," or "&" no luck

This is what i did, only 1 shows up.. the code works normal as i delete 1 of them the otherone shows up...

```
function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("Mac").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readMac", true);
  xhttp.send();
}


//GET LIVE SSID
function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("SSID").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readSSID", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

this is where the device shows up

```
<tr>
    <td><i class='fas fa-chalkboard w3-text-blue w3-large'></i></td>
    <td>MAC.</td>
    <td><span id="Mac">0</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><i class='fas fa-chalkboard w3-text-blue w3-large'></i></td>
    <td>SSID.</td>
    <td><span id="SSID">0</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the same function name `getData()` multiple times, it will always be overwritten. So you could change the name (which would be horrible code) or (better) use the function with parameters. Something like `getData(id)`

```js
function getData(id, blubber) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", blubber, true);
  // if above line is always with "read"+id you could also do
  // xhttp.open("GET", "read"+id, true); // and remove "blubber" parameter
  xhttp.send();
}


getData('Mac', 'readMac');
getData('SSID', 'readSSID');
```

Comment: it does not update my changes.. when i refresh the webpage the info pops up but the value stays static and doesnt update

Comment: I forget to mention i have this in there aswell, but it doesnt update... how to set it up ?  ```setInterval(function() {
  // Call a function repetatively with 2 Second interval
  getData();
}, 2000); //2000mSeconds update rate```

Comment: @user3785784 looks like you have two more DIFFERENT questions. Your first comment was like: "Yes it work.." you might need to ask another question, or do some research yourself.